# Building Swift in Sublime Text 2

Tags: swift, sublimetext2

These build settings for my `swift.sublime-build` file seem to almost work:

```
{
    "cmd": ["swift $file_name"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "path": "/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/",
    "selector": "source.swift",
    "shell": true
}
```

But I'm getting this on build:

```
<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'CoreGraphics'
<unknown>:0: note: did you forget to set an SDK using -sdk or SDKROOT?
<unknown>:0: note: use "xcrun -sdk macosx swift" to select the default OS X SDK installed with Xcode
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

My application is console output only, so I don't even need `CoreGraphics`. I'm not sure how to subvert that requirement or how to use the `-sdk` parameter.

Comment: beta 6 is out already :)

Comment: lol. I know. I'm hoping the build settings are the same.

Comment: What command would you use if you were compiling from the command line? Are there any special environment variables you have to set, like `SDKROOT`, and if so what values do you set them to?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I just have a couple of `swift` files that compile command-line output to Xcode's console and I would like that output to instead go to Sublime's console.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Xcode 6.2

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/xcrun", "swift", "$file"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
{
  "shell_cmd": "xcrun swift $file"
}
```